# How to Avoid Duplicate copies of Base Class Members in Derived Class in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, static, macros, constants

In my project, there is one Base class and there are 3 different derived classes. I have some macro variables written as const int  in the base class. All the derived member is going to access these members and are going to see the same value. Since, its a const, and it is not going to change, maintaining 3 different values will be waste of space. Hence I want a way to maintain just one copy of base class const members so that all the derived class will use the same.

Example

```
 //Base.hpp
 Class Base {

       const int ZER0;
       const int ONE;
 };

 //Derived1.hpp
 class Derived1:public Base {
      int some_method1(); 
 };

  //Derived1.cpp

  int Derived1::some_method1() {

    int value = ZERO;
  }

 //Derived2.hpp

 class Derived2:public Base {
    int some_method2();
 };

//Derived2.cpp

int Derived2::some_method2() {
   int value = ONE;
}

//main.cpp

Derived1 d1;
d1->some_method1();

Derived d2;
d2->some_method2();
```

//Here in both the methods the values are constant, but still the ZERO and ONE are going to have different space. Is there a way, where I maintain only one copy? I could think of static variable. Is it okay to use static inside class and where do I initialize the static variable. Please advice.

PS: This questions might be a duplicate, but I cant find something with similar words, if you feel this is, please feel free to redirect to the corresponding article/question;

Comment: I smell "My First home-grown RTTI implementation" here, and if so, just use `dynamic_cast` for such things.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using `static` class members.

Comment: ^Yeah, I guess static is the way to go, I am going to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, would an **enum** do what you're looking for?

```
class Base
{
    enum 
    {
        ZERO,
        ONE
    };
};
```

Comment: Well it Depends, ZERO and ONE are just examples in my program, not necessarily ZERO and ONE is followed by two. Of course we can use enum for defining variables, but my question would be if enum has ZERO and ONE, how many copies will be seen by the derived class d1 and d2? if there is going to be two, nope, if the copies will be only one for both the elements, yes, this is what I am looking for :)

Comment: @howtechstuffworks an enum constant is not a variable but a literal value hard-wired into your program at compile-time; there aren't any "copies" - it won't even contribute to the sizeof your class or any of your objects since it doesn't have a presence in memory (you can't take the address-of an enum constant because it doesn't have an address).   Of course, you may still declare int variables to store those values, but the enum declaration itself has no runtime footprint.

Comment: Wow, then this would help I guess, Thanks!. One more questions, so I can declare the enum inside my class and access it in derived class right? or else enum does not care about classes?

Comment: yes, the enum will be subject to exactly the same access/visibility rules as anything else you might have declared in there (including member-functions, member-variables, typedefs, inner-classes, etc).  Since a derived class is just an extension of a base class, specifying Base::ZERO will have exactly the same meaning as Derived::ZERO (Assuming that you didn't "hide" the base definition in the derived class with something else)

Comment: but I guess enum does not have address, coz I might need to write some function like read((char*)&ONE, sizeof(int)) // something like that so I might need an address? Will enum still work or static const is the way to go in that case? (I assume static const have address :) )

Comment: Yes you'd need to declare a variable in order to do that, but it doesn't sound like a good idea to me;   the **static** keyword would make it into a global variable, and by modifying it's value you'd be violating the **const** promise which you'd made to the compiler.    You'd probably be better off declaring another variable to pass to your read function.

Comment: I wont be modifying it, I will just pass the static constant, so that it can copy the values. the read function is a part of fstream.h, my code will look like, fstream file("file.bin",ios::out|ios::binary); file.read((char*)&ONE, sizeof(int)); Here file.read,will copy the binary bits into file. I wont change the ONE value. I declared it as static const ONE;

Comment: Ah I see now. Stepping off-topic a little, the function you'll need would be ::write() instead of ::read().     But in any case, you'll be fine to take the address-of a **static const int**.

Comment: yeah yeah, I am sorry, its write(), read() is used somewhere else in the program that does not affect this variable, LOL, good eye :) Sorry for the confusion, should have been clearer

Answer (score 0):

I think you can possibly use virtual base inheritence to maintain one copy of base ..

```
//Base.hpp
class Base {
public:
    Base() {}
    virtual ~Base() {}
protected:
    static const int ZER0;
    static const int ONE;
};

//Base.cpp
const int Base::ZER0 = 0;
const int Base::ONE = 1;

//Derived1.hpp
class Derived1 : public virtual Base {  //using virtual keyword here maintains one copy of base class, thus one copy of ONE and ZERO for all objects since they are static members of Base. You must read about diamond problem of virtual inheritence to understand this properly.

public:
    Derived1() :Base() {}
    int method1();
};

//Derived1.cpp

int Derived1::method1() {
    int value = ZER0;
    return value;
}

//Derived2.hpp

class Derived2 : public virtual Base {
public:
    Derived2() :Base() {}
    int method2();
};

//Derived2.cpp

int Derived2::method2() {
    int value = ONE;
    return value;
}

//main.cpp


int main() {
    Derived1 d1;
    d1.method1();  // . instead of -> , -> is used for member access through pointers

    Derived2 d2;
    d2.method2();

    return 0;
}
```